# Get the count of attributes using xpath in java without dom parser

Tags: java, xml, xpath, sax, s9api

I want to fetch the count of attributes using xpath in java. I know we can use DOM parsers but my input file is going to be very large. I can't really use SAX as there are multiple nested tags I need to take care of. I'm also not sure what all attributes are going to be inside the xml document. Having xpath would make my life easier but im really worried dom parser will choke the memory. I read about s9 apis but coudn't really solve it. Are there any other alternate libraries in JAVA that uses xpath without DOM parser? Sharing examples would be really helpful

Lets say my input is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<cricketers>
    <continent>
        <team>
            <aussies>
                <cricketer type="righty">
                    <name>Smith</name>
                    <role>Captain</role>
                    <position>Wicket-Keeper</position>
                </cricketer>
                <cricketer type="lefty">
                <name>Warner</name>
                <role>Batsman</role>
                <position>Point</position>
                </cricketer>
            </aussies>

        </team>
    </continent>

    <continent>
        <team>
            <england>
                <cricketer type="righty">
                    <name>Morgan</name>
                    <role>Captain</role>
                    <position>Covers</position>
                </cricketer>
                <cricketer type="lefty">
                <name>Cook</name>
                <role>Batsman</role>
                <position>Point</position>
                </cricketer>
            </england>

        </team>
    </continent>

  <continent>
        <team>
            <aussies>
                <cricketer type="righty">
                    <name>Smith</name>
                    <role>Captain</role>
                    <position>Wicket-Keeper</position>
                </cricketer>
                <cricketer type="lefty">
                <name>Warner</name>
                <role>Batsman</role>
                <position>Point</position>
                </cricketer>
            </aussies>

        </team>
    </continent>
</cricketers>
```

Given an xpath //team/aussies/cricketer, the count is 4 in this case.
I want to implement something like this without DOM parser

Comment: Streaming in XSLT 3 with Saxon 10 or 9.9 EE might be able to do it, but it requires a license. It is not really clear to me why SAX doesn't suffice it you just want to count all attributes, you might want to explain a bit more what kind of input you have and which attributes you want to count.

Comment: And then there are XML databases like BaseX that should allow you to first integrate a huge document into a db and then to query it without necessarily running into the performance problems of pure in-memory XPath.

Comment: Do you really just want a count of the total number of attributes in the document? That's very easy to do with SAX. Or do you want some more sophisticated statistics? If so, please explain exactly what.

Comment: Consider to edit your question and to show first a representative sample of the XML you want to process and then a description and sample of the result you want to create with XPath. Some paths are streamable in XSLT 3 with streaming, others are not. Counting "attributes" is usually doable with streaming but I am not sure your definition of "attribute" means "attribute" of an element node.

Comment: And often, with XSLT 3 and streaming, using accumulators is a powerful tool to "count" certain nodes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I edited my question as suggested. let me know if you need more clarity

Comment: See the edited answer, doing a single transformation to compute `count( //team/aussies/cricketer)` should work with XSLT 3 and streaming. However, predicates using child selection like e.g. `count(//team/aussies/cricketer[role = 'foo'])` is not streamable. It might be possible to throw in some `count(copy-of(//team/aussies/cricketer)[role = 'Batsman'])`, however.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen If i want to find count of multiple xpaths, do i need to create multiple xsl files? And, also what does load30 method mean?

Comment: If you want to learn and use XSLT 3 with streaming I suggest you install a copy of Saxon 10 EE and request an evaluation license from Saxonica. As for your two question, the `load30` method is just part of the `XsltExecutable` API in s9api to construct an `Xslt30Transformer`, see the Saxon API documentation on saxonica.com for details. Using several paths making different downward selections will fail with streaming in a single stylesheet, unless you try to rely on `xsl:fork`.

Comment: In general, to learn and use XSLT 3 with streaming, you will need to take a step back from your existing XSLT/XPath skills and start with an introduction like https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/sourcedocs/streaming/. As I said initially, the other option to use XPath against huge XML document (sets), is to insert them into a database like BaseX, then you can use XQuery (of which XPath is a subset) against the db and it depends on your query and the optimizer how much memory that consumes. But it might an easier way than trying to learn XSLT 3 with streaming.

Comment: Another option to count various nodes with a single streaming stylesheet would be to set up accumulators doing so.

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 3 supporting streaming (e.g. with Saxon EE 10 or 9.9) you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="adaptive"/>
  
  <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="count(//@*)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if the task is really only to count all attributes. Saxon should run that in a single, forwards only parse through the whole document without building a full tree of all nodes.

Counting elements selected without predicates doing child selection, like

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="count(//team/aussies/cricketer)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

should also work.

In the s9api, you simply need to make sure you pass in the input document as a stream to the Xslt30Transformer e.g.

```
    Processor processor = new Processor(true);

    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();

    XsltExecutable executable = compiler.compile(new StreamSource("count-example1.xsl"));

    Xslt30Transformer transformer = executable.load30();

    XdmValue result = transformer.applyTemplates(new StreamSource("sample1.xml"));

    System.out.println(result);
```